# How to add conditional select in nested SQL query?

Tags: sql

From a database table which contains the number of car and sold_date on every particular date, I am trying to calculate the variance of cars sold between 2 ranges of dates.
The problem I face is that I am unable to add an if statement to the nested query (below) that would make the nested statement return a "null" if that condition is false.

```
SELECT sum(CARS_SOLD) as cars_sold,
(SELECT sum(CARS_SOLD) 
FROM <DB>
WHERE date(date_sold) BETWEEN '2023-01-21' AND '2023-01-31'
) as cars_sold_old
FROM <DB>
WHERE date(date_sold) BETWEEN '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-11'
```

In the above query, all I want to do is that if the distinct number of dates between the two date ranges is different, the nested statement should return null.

In terms of code:

```
if (count(distinct(date(date_sold))) between '2023-01-21' AND '2023-01-31' !== 
count(distinct(date(date_sold))) between '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-11')
return null;
```

Just to clarify, the count in most cases won't be same, I have modified the actual problem in terms of cars_sold but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `SELECT COUNT()` will return a scalar value which can be comared on equality

```
SELECT sum(CARS_SOLD) as cars_sold,
(SELECT 
IF(
(SELECT count(distinct(date(date_sold))) FROM <DB> WHERE date(date_sold)  between '2023-01-21' AND '2023-01-31')   =   
(SELECT count(distinct(date(date_sold))) FROM <DB> WHERE date(date_sold) between '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-11') ,
    sum(CARS_SOLD) , NULL) sum_
FROM <DB>
WHERE date(date_sold) BETWEEN '2023-01-21' AND '2023-01-31'
) as cars_sold_old
FROM <DB>
WHERE date(date_sold) BETWEEN '2023-02-01' AND '2023-02-11'
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but this won't work. The reason I said that the count in most cases would not be the same is because, for a LOT of dates, there won't be any entry in the db. Between any 2 date ranges, I want equality between the number of days that actually exist in the db.

Comment: That's why the similar pseudocode part that I wrote consists of:
count(distinct(date(date_sold))) between RANGE1 == RANGE2

Comment: ok, i have changed te answer, to fit your description